# Pow Wow's in North America -

Tags: native-americans

Were there great pow wows that brought together Aztec-Yaqui -Tarahumara with those of the northern tribes like the Zuni -Hopi -Navajo ?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking - I'm not sure you've provided enough context to enable the majority of people to understand what you're asking. I'm somewhat familiar and I'm not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: A quick word on [pow-wow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pow_wow) (from someone with Osage family and who has attended one): When used by a Native American, consider it the **English** word for a tribe's great meetings or intertribal gatherings. So basically this is asking if those sets of tribes are known to have participated in a large intertribal gathering.